# how to restore missing video folder in nautilus

Tags: 15.04

Please kindly assist me in restoring my missing video folder on nautilus, i mistakenly cut the folder icon and save on my external hard drive. would like to know how i can get the video icon folder back to nautilus. am running ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 6):

Edit the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and change the line `XDG_VIDEOS_DIR` to

```
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

You may need to restart your session

Comment: am a new user. on the terminal

Comment: You could use any editor you like like gedit

Comment: so sorry you mean open gedit and type

Comment: XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"

Comment: Ending Nautilus and restarting it was enough for me. 
No session restart necessary on Fedora 28/Gnome

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I just started my laptop and my Videos folder was gone. I later found my Videos folder in my .gnupg folder after using disk analyser to check my disk usage. Thanks to the fact that I have over 300gb of videos it was on the top of disk usage folders

Comment: The .gnupg folder is in the user's root folder

Comment: If this comment which appears to be the case adds info to the answer use EDIT and add it, do not add as a comment.